# d3.js not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm playing with the JavaScript library d3.js (http://d3js.org/) but I can't find out why this is working in Safari and Firefox but not in Chrome.

I guess the header is right:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js">
  </script>
</head>
```

I also tried to put the script-tag at the end of the file.
Has anyone experience with d3.js?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specify "not working". Also it is called "d3.js" and not "3d"

Comment: it doesn't show anything whats between the script tag where I use 3d.js. Neither the axes nor the data.

Comment: In the above code-sample you just load the library and create no chart. Have a look at the examples' code to see how to get to a chart.

Comment: If your host page is accessed via scheme `https`, Chrome may block an `http` script tag; it is fussier than most browsers in this respect. Check your test page URL.

Comment: of course I create a chart - I didn't post it, because it is working in others browsers.. I just thought there is something with chrome that I have to keep in mind when I work with javascript.

Comment: Outside of chrome blocking d3.js from loading (like what Jim Blackler commented) it shouldn't be causing an issue. Can you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or give us a live link?

Comment: thank you guys, especially @Jim Blacker!

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the library from the recommended address

```
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

also put it before the end of the `</body>` tag so it loads at the end.